# install error with rails 4 using sudo gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, installation

recently upgraded to os x , `installed ruby 2.0` trying to install `rails 4`

> Neils-MacBook-Pro:code neilpatel$ rails --version

Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

```
Neils-MacBook-Pro:code neilpatel$ sudo gem install rails 

Fetching: i18n-0.6.5.gem (100%) Successfully installed i18n-0.6.5 Fetching: multi_json-1.8.2.gem (100%) Successfully installed multi_json-1.8.2 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38.gem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem install rails --version=4.0.0.rc1
```

The version of rails should be specified before installing the gem.

if your `ruby version is 2.0.0` then install the `rails 4` gem.